# How to inherit parent to two viewControllers that each have the same field?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have on storyboard 2 viewControllers each have `UITextField` with the same name.
And I have a parent class that hold the property name of  the `UITextField`.
The parent class inherit the generic `UIViewController` class
and each (my)viewController inherit the parent class.

How can I link the propery name (at the parent class) to both (my)viewContrllers ?

Comment: your question is not clear. You have a parent controller witch has a UITextField and you would like that two other controller inherit the UITextField ?

Comment: I have 2 UITextView each on different UIViewController that inherit parent class that hold 1 property for UITextView. I want to link the propery to both UITextView in the UI.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the `UITextField` property has the `IBOutlet` annotation in the parent class. If the two UIViewControllers are inherited from your super class, than you should be able to see the outlet in the xib and link it as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I think you should do it:

- Have a base vc and two child controllers. Lets call them baseVC and Child1VC, Child2VC
- Base VC won't have a xib file, Child1 and Child2VC's will have. Owners of the xib files are also the child view controllers. themselves.
- Add two textview controllers to child vc's. They may have different sizes, text colors etc but should be of the same class, may be UITextField or a custom textfield implementation.
- Connect the textfield of Child1VC as an IBOutlet to parent VC's .h file. It will be a public outlet, so that you will be able to reach it by self.textfield from the child VC's. The owners of the xib files should extend base VC, otherwise you will not be able to connect it.
- Connect the other textfield from Child2VC to baseVC's .h file as the same textfield outlet, you have previously created.

Now if you did everything connect, you should be able to modify the textfields from child view controllers, but the outlet will belong to BaseVC. I have not used storyboards before, so you need to modify this a little bit according to your needs.