# Inherit outlets and actions in view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

i've create TabBar App with 5 tabs, all 5 views are the same and each view include buttons to control one set of equipment, switch input to output on receiver and control volume, so 5 views correspond to 5 rooms.
Now i have 5 different `UIViewCOntrollers` with nerly the same code, inherited from `UIViewController`.

But i think it should be one RoomViewController, inhereted from `UIViewController`, and RoomViewCOntroller shold be used for each room, something like this

```
class RoomViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var videoSat: UIButton!

   func lockAudioLabel(sender: UIButton) {
      if sender.isSelected {
         return
      } 
      videoSat.isSelected = false
   }

  @IBAction func videoSatSelect(_ sender: UIButton) {

    //send command to equipment
    //make some actions
    lockVideoLabel(sender: sender)
  }
}
```

And Room1ViewController is

```
class Room1ViewController: RoomViewController {
}
```

All rooms have scene in storyboard

So the question is there any way to use one set of iboulets and ibactions in RoomViewController class and inherit them for example in Room1ViewContoller? And how to access them?

Comment: Look into these links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764282/how-to-inherit-parent-to-two-viewcontrollers-that-each-have-the-same-field
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30822817/connecting-objects-with-two-view-controllers-in-swift
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27449771/iboutlet-to-two-viewcontrollers-on-two-storyboards-is-that-possible

Comment: Thanks for links

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So the question is there any way to use one set of iboulets and ibactions in RoomViewController class and inherit them for example in Room1ViewContoller?

The `@IBOutlet` properties and `@IBAction` methods you declare in RoomViewController *are* inherited by subclasses such as Room1ViewController.

But what is *not* inherited is the design in the nib. When you instantiate a subclass like Room1ViewController, it loads its own view, not some other view controller's view. This loading takes place on a per-instance basis. Therefore, you still need to hook up the interface objects *in the nib* to the properties and methods in the class declaration. In other words, you still need to make outlets and actions in the nib, because this is a different view.